# How do I enable compression for my API on the linux service plan?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying a .net-core web API to the Linux app service plan. I haven't created a DOCKERFILE. Just building production release and deploying. Based on the response headers in production, it appears to be using the Kestrel server. I found in the MS documentation that one can enable compression in the code. This approach seems to work perfectly locally, **however I do not see the `Content-Encoding` header on my web API call while in production.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below code in your startup.cs file. It works for me.

```
// Configure Compression level
services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);

// Add Response compression services
services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
});
```

And you also need add `app.UseResponseCompression();` in configure function.

**Test Result:**

[image]

[image]

**My Startup.cs file.**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace corewebapp_linux
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Configure Compression level
            services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);

            // Add Response compression services
            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
            });
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "corewebapp_linux", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "corewebapp_linux v1"));
            }
            app.UseResponseCompression();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```